# Setting system properties using docker-compose.yml

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose

According to [logging.yml](https://github.com/docker-library/elasticsearch/blob/master/1.4/config/logging.yml#L1-L2) in the elasticsearch image, it should be possible to

> .. override the log level by setting a system property, for example -Des.logger.level=DEBUG

How can I override the logger level in the es image I start from docker-compose.yml?

**My docker-compose.yml**

```
elasticsearch:
  image: elasticsearch:1.4.2
  ports:
    - "9200:9200"
    - "9300:9300"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can override whole logging.yml file:

```
elasticsearch:
  ...
  volumes:
     - config/logging.yml:/PATH/TO/logging.yml
```

Comment: Thanks! That made be able to add a custom logging.yml file. I tried to change `es.logger.level: INFO` to `es.logger.level: DEBUG`, but that does not give any more output. Should I change other values too?